# How can I escape the ampersand in a sql query from WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I am trying to query a database in WebMatrix, something I've done several times, only this time, I have found some fields in the vendors column contain ampersands. I have looked over several articles, but none attack this solution from a WebMatrix point of view (actually, none really solve the direct issue, at all, and are instead work arounds for that specific environment).

I have also tried several things including C#'s Replace method (although, I was never able to get a clear example of what I should replace the ampersand with, if anything exists as a suitable replacement, that is), and escaping the ampersand with a backslash (clearly this didn't work).

What would be ideal would be an escape character in the sql environment itself, but, afaik, no such escape character exists.  What should I replace the following query with to return rows whose fields contain ampersands, like so:

```
SELECT vendor_id FROM vendors WHERE vendor_name = 'J & H Equipment'
```

The above query returns no rows even though the vendor_name column contains a value (string) that is exactly 'J & H Equipment'

It bares mentioning that I am parameterizing my queries, so the actual query looks like:

```
string selectQueryString = "SELECT ap_vendor_id FROM ap_vendors WHERE ap_vendor_name = @0";

var code = db.QueryValue(selectQueryString, searchString);
```

After this code, I simply write the value to the page (with razor, and yes I have tried Html.Raw(code) and @code), because this is an AJAX call.

Also, Below is the replace function I have tried running before the actual query:

```
searchString = searchString.Replace("&", "\\&");
```

Note that the double backslashes are necessary as the '\' character is an escape character in C#, so two '\' equates to one '\' in C#.

--------------------------MY SOLUTION---------------------------

For me the solution was to use encodeURIComponent in my javascript before the AJAX call (I'm sure it is clear, by now, that I haven't been using AJAX for long).

Comment: Please post the code you use to query the database.

Comment: If possible, please post the front-end code and the entire method in the code-behind/Controller so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use encodeURIComponent in the javascript before the AJAX call.

Comment: I am using parameterized queries. I didn't want to add that to my post as I thought it would get confusing to some. It actually looks like `SELECT vendor_id FROM vendors WHERE vendor_name = @0`

Comment: Also, I have tried your solution, as I posted in my question, but I will try again (wrapping the @0 in single quotes and replacing the ampersands with '\&', and without wrapping the @0 in single quotes and doing the same)

Comment: @VoidKing: you **should** mention something like that! I was just going to write a comment to that effect... this is very relevant and very important info to have!

Comment: Please post the code that you use to query the database. It will help.

Comment: @Rob I have tried both solutions that you describe in your answer. Neither work and return no rows.

Comment: @Rob I have also tried (ftfoi) to surround the parameter with brackets `[]` and even double quotes `""` Both, however, cause a server error with the jQuery Ajax call (server error 500).

Comment: Have you verified that searchString is in the right format after the ajax call?

Comment: @Rob doing that now, with console.log. Also, this brings up another question, I have never gotten a direct answer (or at least an answer I understand):  What purpose does the @ symbol serve for strings, when used like this?

Comment: @Rob Wait, console.log won't help me, because nothing is written to the page, as no rows are returned.

Comment: @Rob Per your solution above, should I still try to replace the `&` with `\&`?

Comment: If search string comes in as "J & H Equipment" then it should work just fine. I have a feeling it's coming in as "J &amp; H Equipment" or something else. Google the "@", it's a string literal allowing you to enter characters without escaping them. Is your website ASP.NET or MVC? You need to figure out what searchString is.

Comment: @Rob F ME! I think I just realized what it is... I am using 'GET' in the Ajax request (i.e., passing querystring values), so..... it seems I need to URL Encode, I think.

Comment: @Rob I'll try that and get back with you.

Comment: @Rob I got it to work (see my edit in the OP, above) I apologize for being mislead as to what the problem was. THANK YOU so much for your help (P.S. If you add my solution to your answer, I won't have a problem accepting it, as you spent a lot of time trying to help me with this).